# Table Creation query

Tags: sql-server

I want to count values based upon two condition with same column.

Like,

tablename : Status

```
----|-------|------------|
Id  | name  |  status    |
----|-------|------------|
1   |   tg1 |    success |
2   |   tg1 |    Reject  |
3   |   tg2 |    success |
```

output like:

```
ID   success_count     Rejected_count
tg1       1                  1
tg2       0                  1
```

Comment: What does your question have to do with "table creation" (as per the title). Looks like you need a simple-ish `group by` - or `pivot`

Comment: Duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53985159/sql-server-how-to-group-by-value-multiple-columns-for-n-days

Answer (score 3):

The relevant query can be shown the expected result :

```
create Table #Table
(
    Id int,
    NameTg varchar(128),
    StatusTg varchar(128)
)

Insert into #Table
(
    Id,
    NameTg,
    StatusTg
)

SELECT 1,'tg1','success'
UNION
SELECT 2,'tg1','success'
UNION
SELECT 3,'tg2','success'
UNION
SELECT 4,'tg2','Reject'

SELECT NameTg, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN StatusTg = 'success' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Success_count,
    SUM(CASE WHEN StatusTg = 'Reject' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Reject_count
FROM #Table
GROUP BY NameTg

DROP TABLE  #Table
```

RESULT :

```
NameTg   Success_count  Reject_count
tg1           2               0
tg2           1               1
```

Comment: Or alternatively `SELECT *
FROM (SELECT NameTg, StatusTg FROM #Table) T
PIVOT (COUNT(StatusTg) FOR StatusTg IN (success,Reject)) P`

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes PIVOT work's like a charms too :D

Answer (score 3):

You can use pivot as

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (
      SELECT Name, 
             Status 
      FROM T
    ) TT 
PIVOT 
(
  COUNT(Status) 
  FOR Status IN (success,Rejected)
) PVT
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6b4d15929d31d17916ee027a626abfda)**